# Add metadata to my in-app purchase ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My app was rejected because I didn't add metadata to the App Store:

> App Store Metadata
>
> We were unable to find the following in the metadata to be displayed on the App Store.
>
> Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription in your app's description:
>
> Title of publication or service
>
> • Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period)
>
> • Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
>
> • Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
>
> • Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
>
> • Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase
>
> • Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable
>
> ￼– A link to the terms of use in either the app description or EULA field of App Store Connect
>
> ￼– A privacy policy link in the Privacy Policy URL field of App Store Connect

I can't find any metadata on my in-app purchase page in iTunesConnect. Here is my screenshots:

**in-app purchase rejection**:
[image]

**There are no any fields like Title, or Length here**:
[image]

I accurately filled up all fields on the page, and I have no idea how to add metadata to the App Store. Maybe it is in a different place of App Store Connect, but I haven't found it.

Comment: You need to add the relevant information to the actual app description in App Store Connect. You could also probably improve the description of the actual in-app purchase.

Comment: @Paulw11 It is relevant, and the description seems to be right...

Comment: So the general description field for your app contains all of the information that Apple has listed?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. Wait a moment I am going to make screenshots...

Comment: @Paulw11 Here - https://imgur.com/rBNG2fl

Comment: Look at the description for this app https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/vysit/id1148256616?mt=8.  All the text under "subscriptions" is the sort of thing you need to add to your app description.

Comment: @paulw11 Ok, I am going try to add the subscription part like in you app. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many thanks to @Paulw11! My app was approved. The clue was to insert all metadata text into the app description like:

```
---
Features:
....

Subscription:
[ price / length / title / 
  Account will be charged for 
  renewal within 24-hours 
  prior to the end ... etc ]
---
```

Comment: You inserted all those into app description or auto renewable item description? I found the description field is too short for having all of those information.

Comment: @TomSawyer - all fields are required.

Comment: This is not properly explained please. I got an app rejected for the exact reasons and I have my the proper information available when a user wants to subscribe.

Comment: Been three years since.   Just wanted to post that this problem still persists.  I had the privacy URL set and it was correctly linking to my privacy disclosure page.  I was using the standard Apple dev EULA.  6 rejects.  Over and over.  Same message with faulty instructions to fix it.   And what got it approved?   I put the privacy URL and a URL to Apple's standard EULA at the bottom of my app's description and they passed it.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was approved after adding the following description to the end of the description:

Subscription:

• Title: Upgrade to premium

• Length of subscription: 1 year (length of the subscription)

• Price of subscription: price / Year

• Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase

• Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal

• Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase

• Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable

Terms and conditiosns: link to terms and conditions

Privacy policy: link to privacy policy

Answer (score 0):

Actually the User should be informed in the application itself about the items listed in Alex's or Kkkk Kkkk's response.

Users should know exactly what they are buying/subscribing to. Therefore I actually interpret the Apple Human Interface Guidelines that you have to make them visible to the user before he starts with the inApp Process.

And in my opinion each developer should have the courtesy to the user to show those information in the application, this shouldn't be an Apple requirement only.